# Android prevent bitmap being scaled down when reading file

Tags: android, bitmap, android-bitmap

I'm reading a jpg file into bitmap. The file I'm reading has dimensions 1600x1600 but the bitmap has dimensions 600x600. Why is it being scaled down? Here is my code:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inScaled = false;
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
options.inMutable = true;

b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile, options);

Log.d("###", "bitmapWidth: " + b.getWidth());
Log.d("###", "bitmapHeight: " + b.getHeight());
```

I get the following log:

```
12-19 10:03:10.551: D/###(4125): bitmapWidth: 600
12-19 10:03:10.551: D/###(4125): bitmapHeight: 600
```

As you can see I have the `inScaled` flag set to false. Why is it being scaled down?

**EDIT:**
I even tried with `inJustDecodeBounds` and I got the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code sholud work as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6806321/2591002) but not getting why it's not working..

Add these lines

```
  options.inDensity = 0;
  options.inTargetDensity = 0;
  options.inSampleSize = 1;
```

1 will works as written [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize)

```
"The sample size is the number of pixels in either dimension that correspond to a single pixel in the decoded bitmap. For example, inSampleSize == 4 returns an image that is 1/4 the width/height of the original, and 1/16 the number of pixels. Any value <= 1 is treated the same as 1. Note: the decoder uses a final value based on powers of 2, any other value will be rounded down to the nearest power of 2."
```

Comment: This way I got 300x300. That's even smaller :)

Comment: it has to be int value

Comment: and just to mention... images can have different sizes.

Comment: I guess 1 will work.. The sample size is the number of pixels in either dimension that correspond to a single pixel in the decoded bitmap. For example, inSampleSize == 4 returns an image that is 1/4 the width/height of the original, and 1/16 the number of pixels. Any value <= 1 is treated the same as 1. Note: the decoder uses a final value based on powers of 2, any other value will be rounded down to the nearest power of 2.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43490/discussion-between-tamanna-and-nikmin)