# Android Drawable getBitmap size mismatch

Tags: android, bitmap, resources

I am loading some image using

```
    Resources resources = WatchFaceService.this.getResources();
    Drawable spritesDrawable = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.sprites);
    mSpritesBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)spritesDrawable).getBitmap();
```

R.drawable.sprites is a 640x700 PNG, yet

```
    Log.d( TAG, "SpritesBitmap=" + mSpritesBitmap.getWidth() + "x" + mSpritesBitmap.getHeight());
```

outputs **960x1050**
Where does the 1.5 scale come from?

Comment: Android sometimes scales Bitmaps when you load them, did you try loading it diffrently? like this for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805355/i-dont-want-android-to-resize-my-bitmap-automatically

Comment: That was indeed related to resource path. Moving the PNG file to drawables-nodpi did the trick. Please post as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android sometimes scales Bitmaps when you load them, did you try loading it differently?
For clarity, if your resource is located in `./drawable/` they may end up scaled
You can prevented this by moving the resource to `./drawable-nodpi/`
see: [I don't want Android to resize my bitmap Automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805355/i-dont-want-android-to-resize-my-bitmap-automatically)